# Perl remote write file connection error message Net::SFTP::Foreign

Tags: perl, ssh, sftp, perl-module, ssh-keys

When I manually run this Perl script, it can establish a connection. But when I implement into the system, it shows this: `authenticity of the target host can't be established, the remote host public key is probably not present on the '~/.ssh/known_hosts' file`.

I need help and advice on this.

```
my $host = "xxxs.com";
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host,user => 'xxx', password => 'xxx',
                                   more => '-v',stderr_fh => $ssherr);
```

Comment: If you could put the rest of the code it may help more.

What do you mean "implement into the system"?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [FAQ](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.73/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm#FAQ) in the Net::SFTP::Foreign doc. It's filed under **Host key checking** and is the last entry. Here's an excerpt.

> Host key checking
>
> Q: Connecting to a remote server with password authentication fails
>   with the following error:
>
> ```
> The authenticity of the target host can not be established,
> connect from the command line first
> ```
>
> A: That probably means that the public key from the remote server is
>   not stored in the `~/.ssh/known_hosts file`. Run an SSH Connection from
>   the command line as the same user as the script and answer yes when
>   asked to confirm the key supplied.

There is also an example there.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was:

```
my $ftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new( $HOST, 
                                    user => $USERNAME, 
                                    password => $PASSWORD, 
                                    more => [-o => 'StrictHostKeyChecking no'] );
```

Where StrictHostKeyChecking did the trick.

ref: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=Net::SFTP::Foreign

Comment: Don't disable strict host key checking unless you know what you are doing! Quoting the [module documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#Host-key-checking): "Your SSH client may also support some flag to disable this check (strict host key), but doing it can ruin the security of the SSH protocol so I advise against its usage"